# How to automatically share my iPhone's internet connection with my MacBook

Tags: network, ios, macos, tethering

I believe I heard from the Apple keynote that with the release of Yosemite and iOS 8 we will be able to automatically share the iPhone's internet connection without having to connect every time with hotspot (when within range). I now have Yosemite on my MacBook and iOS 8 on my iPhone, but I cannot see any options to enable this automatic connection. I currently connect with bluetooth to get my iPhone's internet connection.

Did I misunderstand or is there such an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8.1, I believe, releasing next Monday 20 Oct.

Ref : http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/10/17/yosemite-updaters-will-need-to-wait-for-mondays-ios-81-launch-for-sms-relay-instant-hotspot